# Delta live tables data quality checks

Tags: databricks, delta-live-tables

I'm using delta live tables from Databricks and I was trying to implement a complex data quality check (so-called expectations) by following [this guide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDR5e.png). After I tested my implementation, I realized that even though the expectation is failing, the tables dependent downstream on the source table are still loaded.

To illustrate what I mean, here is an image describing the situation.

[Image of the pipeline lineage and the incorrect behaviour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDR5e.png)

I would assume that if the report_table fails due to the expectation not being met (in my case, it was validating for correct primary keys), then the Customer_s table would not be loaded. However, as can be seen in the photo, this is not quite what happened.

Do you have any idea on how to achieve the desired result? How can I define a complex validation with SQL that would cause the future nodes to not be loaded (or it would make the pipeline fail)?

Comment: Can you show your Notebook so we can help diagnose? Have you seen expect_or_drop and expect_or_fail (https://docs.databricks.com/workflows/delta-live-tables/delta-live-tables-expectations.html). My suspicion is that your DAG should just include Customer and Customer_s, with the definition of Customer_s having the constraints. I'm not sure I understand what report_table is.

Answer (score 1):

The default behavior when expectation violation occurs in Delta Live Tables is to load the data but track the data quality metrics (retain invalid records). The other options are : ON VIOLATION DROP ROW and ON VIOLATION FAIL UPDATE. Choose "ON VIOLATION DROP ROW" if that is the behavior you want in your pipeline.
https://docs.databricks.com/workflows/delta-live-tables/delta-live-tables-expectations.html#drop-invalid-records